# Electric potential of a spheroidal gaussian

Tags: mathematical-physics, research-level, electrostatics, specific-reference

I'm looking for results that compute the electrostatic potential due to a spheroidal gaussian distribution. Specifically, I'm looking for solutions of equations of the form
$$
\nabla^2\Phi=N\exp\left({-\rho^2/2\sigma_r^2}\right)\exp\left({-z^2/2\sigma_\ell^2}\right),
$$
where $\rho^2=x^2+y^2$, possibly with some polynomial factor of the form $\rho^{|m|}\cos(m\phi)z^n$ in front.

This has an [easy solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson%27s_equation#Potential_of_a_Gaussian_charge_density) when the two variances $\sigma_r$ and $\sigma_\ell$ are equal, in which case there is spherical symmetry applies and Gauss's law readily yield $\Phi$ in terms of error functions.

However, I'm having trouble finding results for the general case. Using [spheroidal coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolate_spheroidal_coordinates) doesn't seem to help, as the constant-$\mu$ surfaces are confocal spheroids that taper out to spheres as they get larger, instead of maintaining their ellipticity as the charge density does.

This looks standard enough that it ought to have been done before (right?), but it is also messy enough that I'm unsure it made it to any textbook. Has anyone seen the likes of this before?

Comment: Just took a quick look, but why doesn't separation of variables work?

Comment: Using [cylindrical harmonics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_harmonics#Point_source_in_open_space_at_origin) the $z$ integral comes out to $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp\left(-\frac{z'^2}{2\sigma_\ell}-k|z-z'|\right)\mathrm{d}z'$ which is doable, in terms of error functions, but then chokes the $k$ integral.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty - I bugged one of my mathematically inclined colleagues (because I thought I had seen this before and it was driving me nuts that I could not find any reference to it).  He suggested converting to oblate spherical coordinates so that Laplace's equation becomes separable with solutions given as series of oblate spherical harmonics (i.e., related to Lamé functions).

Comment: @honeste That won't work, for the reasons pointed out in the question. There's no orthogonal coordinate system whose equicoordinate surfaces have a constant charge density with this distribution. (Or you should clarify what you mean.)

Comment: @EmilioPisanty - So my friend disagrees about the existence of an orthogonal coordinate system.  I will just quote him for simplicity:  "It is, however, manifestly untrue that there is no orthogonal system with coordinate surfaces that correspond to source isosurfaces, as all you need to do is define a new coordinate from the argument of the exponential, keep the azimuthal angle, and puzzle out the third basis as needed. Such a coordinate system is probably not separable, however, and may not be entirely trivial to figure out an analytical expression for the third coordinate."

Comment: @honeste_vivere Your original suggestion, however, was to use oblate spheroidal harmonics, and those do *not* match the charge as given: oblate spheroidal harmonics describe confocal ellipsoids of variable eccentricity, whereas the iso-density surfaces of the problem have constant eccentricity and moving foci. If you can show a new set of orthogonal coordinates that includes $\sqrt{\rho^2+\gamma z^2}$ and show that the laplacian separates in a useful fashion, then I'm all ears.

Comment: (Otherwise, this four-year-old question's practical utility for me is rather diminished by now, and while I would find any progress interesting, I can't dedicate any significant time to chasing leads ─ particularly as I'm pretty convinced by now that there's simply no clean solution.)

Comment: Your suggestion of a constant-eccentricity system is [useful on its own](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2338169/is-there-an-orthogonal-coordinate-system-built-around-constant-eccentricity-elli), though.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty - Ah okay, yes I see.  I originally read your question and was confused because I was absolutely certain I had see not only this differential equation, but an analytical solution.  When I saw you asked, I was confused because if you had not found the answer, then I must be mistaken.  Regardless, this is completely distracting me because I cannot get my mind to accept that I have not done this before...

Answer (score 1):

$\def\a{\alpha}
\def\p{\pi}
\def\s{\sigma}
\def\f{\varphi}
\def\S{\Sigma}
\def\r{\varrho}
\def\vr{\mathbf{r}}
\def\ur{\mathbf{\hat{r}}}
\def\o{\cdot}
\def\RR{\mathbb{R}}$*Not a complete solution, but too long for a comment.*

Consider the charge density 
$$\r(x,y,z) = Q \f_1(x)\f_2(y)\f_3(z),$$
where 
$$\f_i(u) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\p}\s_i} e^{-u^2/(2\s_i^2)}.$$
Note that $\f_i$ is a normal distribution with zero mean and standard deviation $\s_i$. 
Thus, 
$\int \r(\vr) dV = Q.$
We find 
\begin{align*}
\int \frac{\r(\vr')}{|\vr-\vr'|}dV'
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{r^{n+1}} \int_{r'\le r} \r(\vr') P_n(\ur\o\ur'){r'}^n dV' \\
&\quad + \sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n \int_{r'>r} \r(\vr') P_n(\ur\o\ur')\frac{1}{{r'}^{n+1}} dV',
\end{align*}
where $P_n$ is the $n$th Legendre polynomial. 
For $r\gg \max(\s_i)$ this will be well-approximated by 
$$I = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{r^{n+1}} \int_{\RR^3} \r(\vr') P_n(\ur\o\ur'){r'}^n dV'.$$
Since $P_n$ is odd if and only if $n$ is odd we find 
$$I = \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{c_{2m}}{r^{4m+1}},$$
where 
$$c_{2m} = \int_{\RR^3} \r(\vr') P_{2m}(\ur\o\ur')(r {r'})^{2m} dV'.$$
(Note, for example, that $P_1(\ur\o\ur'){r r'}=\vr\o\vr'=x x'+y y'+z z'$, which integrates to zero. Thus, the dipole, octupole, ... contributions are zero.)
The first few $c$s are given as 
\begin{align*}
c_0 &= Q \\
c_2 &= \frac{Q}{2} (3\S_{2,2}-\S_{2,0}r^2) \\
c_4 &= \frac{Q}{8} 
    \left(105 \S_{2,2}^2
    -30(\S_{2,2}\S_{2,0}+2\S_{4,2}) r^2
    +3(\S_{2,0}^2+2\S_{4,0}) r^4\right),
\end{align*}
where 
\begin{align*}
\S_{m,n} &= \sum_{i=1}^3 \s_i^m x_i^n.
\end{align*}
This gives the monopole, quadrupole, and hexadecapole contributions to $\Phi$ for $r\gg\max(\s_i)$. 
If $\s_1=\s_2 = \s$ we find
\begin{align*}
c_2 &= \frac{Q}{2}(\s^2-\s_3^2)(x^2+y^2-2z^2) \\
c_4 &= \frac{3Q}{8} (\s^2-\s_3^2)^2(3(x^2+y^2)^2-24(x^2+y^2)z^2+8z^4)
\end{align*}
In principle the $c$s may be calculated generally.
The coefficients of the Legendre polynomials are known and we may expand powers of $\vr\o\vr'$ and ${r'}^{2m}$ as trinomial series. 
The problem is reduced to finding moments of the normal distribution.
We expect corrections due to the assumption that $r\gg\max\s_i$ to be of order 
$\frac{1}{r}\left(1-\mathrm{erf}
\sqrt{\sum_i \frac{x_i^2}{2\s_i^2}}\right)$.